# How to edit/modify NSLayoutConstraint in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, nslayoutconstraint

I drag a tab view into my custom view, and set its frame. Xcode automatically generate several NSLayoutConstraint objects those will decide its frame during auto-layout.

[image]

As shown above, a constraint which indicates the distance between right edge of the tab view and the **RIGHT** edge of its super view.

However, I do not want a constraint like this. What I want is a constraint which indecates the distance between the right edge of the tab view and the **LEFT** edge of its suber view. **OR**, the width of the tab view itself.

How should I do?

BTW, I tried delete the constraint, but Xcode generated this constraint back immediately. Therefore I could not add one (and actually I do not know how to add one, either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a minimum number of constraints required on each axis of the view, hence you should add a new constraint first before deleting existing one to make sure Xcode understands how to layout the views properly.

Try to add a new constraint by clicking a view and then click on the middle button at the bottom right options in your screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Oh, there it is! Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

go through following link, which explain auto layout..

http://www.raywenderlich.com/20881/beginning-auto-layout-part-1-of-2